# yii setting on nginx?

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii, nginx, yii2

I am setting by Yii project on nginx.

I am using `.htaccess` for removing `.index.php` from url.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /web
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

MY project Urls are not working.Getting this error message:

```
  Something has triggered missing webpage on your website. This is the default 404   error page for nginx that is distributed with the Amazon Linux AMI. It is located at /usr/share/nginx/html/404.html

  You should customize this error page for your own site or edit the error_page directive     in the nginx configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.
```

But on `nginx` What I have to do to make my YII project work?

Comment: I am very sure that for a framework like Yii there is enough documentation to be found about Yii and Nginx

Comment: I know @Michal-sk웃 there are many documents on this. But How should I do this.  http://wiki.nginx.org/Yii

Comment: Using apache and nginx? Why do you want this?

Comment: @Bondye some use nginx in front of apache, to have a loadbalancer by nginx and process the php by apache.

Comment: yes @Michal-sk웃 ,You are right.

Comment: https://github.com/filsh/yii2-app-platform

Answer (score -1):

```
server {
    set $host_path "/www/mysite";
    access_log  /www/mysite/log/access.log  main;

    server_name  mysite;
    root   $host_path/htdocs;
    set $yii_bootstrap "index.php";

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        index  index.html $yii_bootstrap;
        try_files $uri $uri/ $yii_bootstrap?$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(protected|framework|themes/\w+/views) {
        deny  all;
    }

    #avoid processing of calls to unexisting static files by yii
    location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;

        #let yii catch the calls to unexising PHP files
        set $fsn /$yii_bootstrap;
        if (-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name){
            set $fsn $fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fsn;

        #PATH_INFO and PATH_TRANSLATED can be omitted, but RFC 3875 specifies them for CGI
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fsn;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

loaded from https://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/trunk/docs/guide/quickstart.apache-nginx-config.txt

Comment: From where I will get this file which I have to edit?

Comment: LOL, why you use nginx if don't know how use it? Listening above is a vhost config, rewrite mode replacement: `#$yii_bootstrap = index.php(see above) location / {
        index  index.html $yii_bootstrap;
        try_files $uri $uri/ $yii_bootstrap?$args;
    }`

Comment: hahahha I want to learn it.

I am getting "No input file specified." error